# A combinatoric identity for characters of reductive groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-combinatorics, weyl-group

Let $G$ be a reductive group over an algebraic closed field (of char 0 if necessary). Let $T\subset G$ be a maximal torus and $S=\mathrm{Sym}^*(X(T))$ be the symmetric algebra of characters of $T$. Let $T\subset B$ be a Borel subgroup and assume the flag variety $G/B$ has dimension $N$. From some geometry perspective, the following identity in $S$ is expected: for any $\lambda\in X(T)$

$$\sum_{w\in W} (-1)^{\ell(w)}w(\lambda^{N+1})=\frac{N+1}{\sharp W} {\sum_{w\in W} (-1)^{\ell(w)}w(\lambda^N)}\sum_{w\in W} w(\lambda).$$

Here $W$ is the  Weyl group and $\ell$ is the length function.

Could anyone give any hint on how to prove such an identity or where to find such kind identity? Thanks in advance!

In the case $G=\mathrm{GL}_2$, one has $N=1$ and $X(T)=\mathbb{Z} \lambda_1\oplus \mathbb{Z}\lambda_2$ where $$\lambda_i: T\to G_m,\quad (x_1,x_2)\mapsto x_i$$
is the i-th projection and one can identify $W$ with $S_2$. In this case, the identity becomes
$$(a\lambda_1+b\lambda_2)^2-(a\lambda_2+b\lambda_1)^2=[(a\lambda_1+b\lambda_2)-(b\lambda_1+a\lambda_2)][(a\lambda_1+b\lambda_2)+(b\lambda_1+a\lambda_2)]$$
which is clearly true.

Comment: The $\lambda^{N+1}$ is a little strange: the rest of what you right suggests you are writing characters additively. Perhaps you can clarify what your expectation says for $SL_2$? Your formula bears a passing resemblance to the formula at the top of page 18 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.06261.pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Here the group law in X(T) is written as addition and multiplication lies in the symmetric algebra S of X(T).  In the case G=GL(n), S is just the ring of polynomials in n-variables.

Comment: Thank you -- you wrote $\textrm{Sym}(X(T))$ and I didn't read carefully enough. Thanks for the $GL_2$ example, I'll have a think if I can find some time...

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestions